# HTML5Boilerplate build script CSS reference in PHP file

Tags: html5boilerplate

I'm trying to build my site with Html5Boilerplate and for the most parts it's going as I whish.
However, I'm still unable to get the CSS reference to update in my PHP file.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
    css/style.css
    page/header.php
```

Now in the header.php file I have:

```
    <!-- scripts concatenated and minified via ant build script-->
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'/>
    <!-- end scripts-->
```

I would expect the built header.php file to have the following:

```
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/a4cd4c0.css'/>
```

But unfortunately it is not updating the reference.

In the project.properties file I have: file.pages = page/*  and it is stripping the comments in the header.php file, so I know the build script doesn't skip the file.

I have tried variaties, like:

```
    <!-- CSS concatenated and minified via ant build script-->
        <link rel='stylesheet/css' type='text/css' href='css/style.css'/>
    <!-- end CSS-->
```

But this hasn't done a thing either . . .

Is there anyone who has tried to update their CSS files with Html5Boilerplate in their PHP files? What could I try to get the reference to be updated by the build script?
And my last question is: Could I let the build script update the reference, if I use the following line for including my CSS?

```
    <link rel='stylesheet/css' type='text/css' href='<?PHP echo(CSS_PATH) ?>style.css'/>
```

**EDIT**:
By fiddling around in the build.xml file, I have not only got it working, but also with my php echo.
Around line 623 of the build.xml file I have changed the lines:

```
    <replaceregexp match="&lt;link rel=['&quot;]?stylesheet['&quot;]?\s+href=['&quot;]?(.*)/${file.root.stylesheet}(?:\?.*)?['&quot;]?\s*&gt;" 
        replace="&lt;link rel='stylesheet' href='\1/${css.sha}.css'&gt;" flags="m">
```

to

```
    <replaceregexp match="href=['&quot;]?(.*\?&gt;)${file.root.stylesheet}(?:\?.*)?['&quot;]?" 
        replace="href='\1${css.sha}.css'" flags="m">
```

Hopefully this helps someone who is running to a similiar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of HTML5Boilerplate you are using, the answer most probably lies in removing the comments in the .htaccess file specifically regarding 'Built-in filename-based cache busting'.

Here is the code section from [HTML5 Boilerplate 4.1](http://html5boilerplate.com/).

```
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ $1.$3 [L]
 </IfModule>`
```

It would be inadvisable to edit or rework the build.xml file;

- It is far more efficient to edit the .htaccess file.
- You increase risk of not being able to future proof your application with updates and releases to HTML5 Boilerplate.